# Call App From Background - Appium/Android

Tags: android, appium

I need to send an app to background, return home and call it from background again in Android, with Appium.
I've alredy tried

```
driver.runAppInBackground(seconds);
```

and

```
driver.launchApp();
```

but they re-launch the application, don't call it.
How should I handle this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, to start home screen:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

And from background service after some time or event, you can start you main activity again the same way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can start any application activity using intents.

Comment: This one didn't work to me, unfortunately. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this just now, but the difference is I called another app(so basically putting the app in background). The way i runned the app from background is long press home button with `adb shell input keyevent --longpress 3`, then used `.click()` on the app i want to run from background. You can use `UIAutomatorViewer` to find the element :). Hope this helps